# How can I find property value from a json FeatureCollection by coordinates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, properties, coordinates, geojson

How can I find property (in this case "icao") values from a json FeatureCollection by coordinates using javascript/jQuery?

I have this:

`var coord = "-86.7703018188,34.8647994995";`

The result should be:
00AL
("icao": "00AL",)

the script so far:

```
var json = (function () {
    json = null;
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': 'myfile.geojson',
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) {
            json = data;
        }
    });
    return json;
})();

points = json;
```

myfile.geojson:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -151.695999146,
          59.94919968
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "icao": "00AK",
        "name": "Lowell Field",
        "elevation": 450,
        "tz": "America/Anchorage"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -86.7703018188,
          34.8647994995
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "icao": "00AL",
        "name": "Epps Airpark",
        "elevation": 820,
        "tz": "America/Chicago"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by myself

```
var geoJSON = json;
var coord = "-86.7703018188,34.8647994995";
var icao;
for(var i = 0; i < geoJSON.features.length; i++){
    if (geoJSON.features[i].geometry.coordinates == coord) {
        icao = geoJSON.features[i].properties.icao;
    }
}
console.log("coordinates " + coord + " == ICAO: " + icao);
```